# Preview Unity asset with all texture types

Tags: texturing, uv, unity

I'm creating an asset for a unity game (Cities Skylines) including textures for diffuse, specular, normal and alpha.
when I set the view to textured I can only see the diffuse map on my model but not combined with the other ones. To see the model I have to import it into the game every time.
Is there a way to preview the asset model in Blender with all textures applied without rendering it?
Greetings

Comment: No, not yet. Cycles material viewport preview is very basic at the moment

Comment: Mmmmmh, what about the Blender Game Engine?